# Use JSON object to store the form data that refreshes again and again

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a jsp form where there are some field whose values I'm taking again and again. I want to temporarily store the data somewhere and store it in Database only when the final submit button is clicked.

This is the form. In this form the first three fields remain same and the other 4 values refresh every time you submit till you want to stop. When you click final done button (a dialog box pops up everytime to ask whether you want to insert more or finally submit the values.) the values should be stored in the database. Until then the values must be temporarily stored in some variable. I could only think of JSON.

Comment: [`localstorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not using postbacks to submit the (non final) value, then simply push the current value of the input into a JavaScript array.

Then when you do the final submit, you will be able to access all of the previous values of the input from the array.

```html
            //Store the values in here     
            var inputValues = [];
             
            //Click event of non-final submit button
            $(yourButton).on("click", function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var submit = confirm("Do you want to submit?");
                if(submit){
                  //submit the values to the database
                }
                else{
                   //Add the current values to the array, this could be as many as you like
                  inputValues.push({
                    input1:$(yourInput).val(),
                    input2:$(yourInput2).val(),
                    input3:$(yourInput3).val(),
                  });

                  //Optional -- Clear the inputs, again as many as you like
                  $(yourInput).val('');      
                  $(yourInput2).val('');   
                  $(yourInput3).val('');   
                }

            })
```

Comment: refreshing the page will lose the values, for persistent storage, `localstorage` is the best route.

Comment: He doesn't mention using postbacks.

Comment: no. The page is not refreshing. Only a part of it is refreshing. @Shouvik

Comment: @rfsupertramp can you please give me an example.

Comment: Edited my answer, does it make sense? :)

Comment: Yes it does. :) But since I get 4 new values each time so should I make an array of object? @rfsupertramp

Comment: Okay edited to include the confirm (dialog) box and to push an object formed of multiple input values into the array.